# Magento 2: Currency rates import not wokring

Tags: magento2, multicurrency, currency-rates

I have setup muticurrency store, with a base currency USD. When i try to import currency through Yahoo Finance Exchange, Fixer.io or Webservicex then it does not import all currency rates. They miss most of the currencies.

Now I need to change the base currency. After changing base currency other USD then Yahoo Finance Exchange, Fixer.io and Webservicex do not import ANY rate.

Whats wrong with it? I want to import rates with base currency other than USD.

Answer (score 0):

small change:
'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}'; with 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=YOUR API KEY&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}'

Answer (score 0):

The three services come with built-in Magento 2 doesn't work anymore. Instead, you could just install this module and configure free currency converter.

https://github.com/thanhdv2811/Magento-2-Currency-Convert

Answer (score -1):

Yes as Webservicex , not any more working , so please ignore that one , also the Yahoo Finance Exchange, Fixer.io API implementation been deprecated.

I am using Fixer.io, inorder to use this, you need to create an account here https://fixer.io/ by filling the necessary details in basic free plan to get the API KEY and the complete API END point.

**In Magento 2:**

Magento

> Root\vendor\magento\module-directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo.php

line number 16 replace

> 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';
>   with 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=YOUR API
>   KEYformat=1?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}'

Now you can import currency rates using fixer.io :).

If you wish you can create one extension to achieve this, but as only minor changes needed i edited the core file, because i know in future updates magento will add these features, else you can create one extension to achieve this without editing the core file.